# Why, if WebAPI action method returns a C# list, in Javascript / Backbone an object is received instead of an array?

Tags: javascript, c#, backbone.js, asp.net-core-webapi

**Situation 1**

I have C# WebAPI with an action that returns a List

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/views/documents")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    [SwaggerOperation("ViewsDocumentsGet")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 200, type: typeof(List<Documents>), description: "...")]
    public virtual IActionResult ViewsDocumentsGet()
    {
        var result = new List<Documents>();
        ...
        return new ObjectResult(result);
    }
```

On the client side, there is a Backbone model, that fetches the documents

```
import { Model } from "backbone";
export default Model.extend({
initialize: function() {
    this._url = arguments[0];
},

url: function(strSwitch) {
    return this._url + `/views/documents`;
},

...
});
```

I call fetch on the model

```
  const response = await this.DocumentsModel.fetch();
  console.log(typeof response, response);
```

The console.log returns

```
object (14) [
0: {DocType: "...", ...}
1: {DocType: "...", ...}
2: ... 
length: 14
__proto__: Array(0)
```

response has type object. I am expecting array.

---

**Situation 2**

If I change the WebAPI action method to return an object that wraps a list, then response is an array.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class DocumentWrapper
    {
        ...
        [DataMember]
        public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/views/documents")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    [SwaggerOperation("ViewsDocumentsGet")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 200, type: typeof(DocumentWrapper), description: "...")]
    public virtual IActionResult ViewsDocumentsGet()
    {
        var result = new DocumentWrapper();
        ...
        return new ObjectResult(result);
    }
```

Now the response is still of type object, but the object has a property Documents which is an array.

```
object {Documents: Array(14)}
        Documents: Array(14)
        0: {DocType: "...", ...}
        1: {DocType: "...", ...}
        2: ... 
        length: 14
        __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
```

---

In situation 1, I know how to convert the object to an array. But I do not want to do that. I want backbone to fetch an array from the API without me having to do any conversion.

**Questions**

1. Why is the C# list not automatically an array?
2. How to tell backbone to fetch an array instead of an object?

Comment: Try to remove the `dataType:'json'`  sentence in your ajax.

Comment: Do accept if you find useful

Answer (score 0):

Backbone model fetch combines the state of the model with attributes fetched from the server by calling `Backbone.sync`.  By default, it uses `jQuery.ajax` to make a RESTful JSON request and returns a `jqXHR`. You can override it in order to use a different persistence strategy but it will always return an jqXHR object because internally it is making ajax requests.